# Codeigniter .htaccess: Give public access to all files but not the folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

my file format like

```
  application
       - controllers
       - views etc...
  assetes
       - Images
       - Css etc...
```

and my .htaccess file are below:

```
#Deny from all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My problem is that assets folder access to every one any user veiw all images and all css file but needed is only user access assets folder file not the access entire folder

please help me
thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blocking directory access can be done by simply putting a `index.html` file in the folder you want to block directory access to.

This is the way the standard CodeIgniter install does it. The below [index.html](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/controllers/index.html) file can be found in the `application\controllers` folder.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the Following lines in your htaccess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
this is for the File accesss

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
this is for the dictory accesss

Comment: Order allow,deny<br/>
Allow from all <br/>
RewriteEngine On <br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f <br/> please update your .htaccess with the following code
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d <br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] <br/>